# gitlab - Synology - automatic synchronisation

Tags: gitlab, synology

im using gitlab on a synology NAS.
for reasons of safety, i would like to automatically synchronise (mirror) the entire gitlab system on my NAS with my account on gitlab.com.

is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your entire gitlab repository is stored under `/volume1/docker/gitlab/repositories` (or a similar directory).

To synchronize, you would need to run a script to push a certain repository (which is in bare mode) to a gitlab. This shows how to do it to GitHub, so it should be similar for gitlab.com:

https://gist.github.com/joahking/780877

Once configured, you can use the task manager in Synology's control panel to execute the script regularly.

Good luck!